# camera streaming with google actions

Tags: camera, raspberry-pi, actions-on-google

I am trying to stream my onboard raspberry camera using google actions. Though the camera is added and synced to cloud in the dashboard. GA does not recognizes that is exists, gives me some random web results.

Anything special needs to be taken care for google action to setup camera?

Any examples or existing project tips is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Define `random web results`

Comment: What exactly have you done so far? Can you provide some more detail?

Comment: @DobromirM When I say "ok google turn on my camera" rather turning on my camera its giving me web-search-results on how to use a camera

Comment: @NickFelker I have deployed the google-action nodes sample project on my raspberry pi from the google-action Git hub page.

Just like every other device camera from the sample project also syncs to the cloud. But I am not able to control it via Google Assistant.

Comment: You are using the Smart Home project?

Does your phone have the `OnOff` trait? Does it have a nickname that you can use, ie. "Turn on smart camera 1"?

Comment: @NickFelker Thanks for pointing out to the traits My traits has only action.devices.traits.CameraStream 
Also in nicknames i have  'backyard camera', 'security camera'  I tried telling GA all i can, yet it still returns web results rather showing me the stream

Comment: If your camera does not have the `OnOff` trait then it can't turn on or off. You should add it.

Comment: How do I Invoke the already present trait? "action.devices.traits.CameraStream" Tried all sorts of keywords/names/nicknames

Comment: I don't know what the right voice syntax would be.